# updating multiple blank fields in one table with data from another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find all fields in one table that are empty and populate them with data from another table.  Here is what I have:

```
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = (
   SELECT col99
     FROM t2
    WHERE t1.product_ID = t2.product_ID
) WHERE col1 IS NULL
```

which works perfectly for updating all the blank fields in col1 of t1.  But I also need to check for blanks in other fields and update them.  I don't want the query to update all the fields each time any one of them is blank, just the blank field.  I could run multiple queries but I have to imagine there is a cleaner, better way.

Thanks,

Matthew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
UPDATE t1
SET
  col1 = COALESCE(col1, (SELECT col99 FROM t2 WHERE t1.product_ID = t2.product_ID)),
  col2 = COALESCE(col2, (SELECT ...)),
  -- etc.
```

Should not perform better than your initial solution. It's just doing the job with only one UPDATE query instead of several.